# JSON query to extract all ids where array is not empty

Tags: sql, arrays, json, azure, azure-cosmosdb

I have a JSON structure similar to this:

```
{  
  "id":"1234"
  "feedback":  {
      "Features": []
 }
}
```

I wish to find all the documents where Features is not an empty array.

This is what I have tried:

```
SELECT * FROM c where ARRAY_LENGTH([c.feedback.Features])> 0
```

I am not sure if this is the correct approach. Any suggestions are appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Your query would not work fine and still return the document in below JSON you provided:

```
{  
  "id":"1234"
  "feedback":  {
      "Features": []
    }
}
```

Would suggest to use the query like below. This will cover when there are zero items present in 'Feature' attribute as well as if 'Feature' attribute is missing altogether.

```
SELECT * FROM c where ARRAY_LENGTH([c.feedback.Features[0]]) > 0
```

Comment: Thank you. Let me try

Answer (score 0):

It should work if you exclude the surrounding brackets from the property path:

```
SELECT * FROM c where ARRAY_LENGTH(c.feedback.Features) > 0
```